# If a point $p$ is an accumulation point of a set S then show that every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of S.

Tags: real-analysis

If a point $p$ is an accumulation point of a set S then show that every neighborhood of $p$ contains infinitely many points of S.

[image]

I am unable to understand the red portion above.

Defn of Limit point: A real number $p$ is said to be a limit point of a set $S \subset\mathbb{R}$ if every nbd of $p$ contains one member of S other than $p$
i.e for $\epsilon>0$, $$N'(p,\epsilon)\cap S\neq \phi$$

Please help me to understand the sentence highlighted in red box.

Comment: Since we take $\epsilon$ as the minimum distance, the nbd contains the point $p$ alone. Think in $\Bbb{R}$ and take $p=0$, $p_1=0.5$, $p_i=n_i > 0.5$ for $i=2,3,...,n$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $U$ is a neighborhood of $p$ such that $U\cap S$ is finite, say $$U\cap S=\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}.$$ Let $\epsilon=\min_{1\leqslant i\leqslant k}\{|p-x_i|\}$. Then the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $p$ does not intsersect $S$, so $p$ is not a limit point of $S$.